# My list items start in right place but end up overflowing div top

Tags: javascript, html, css

My dynamically generated list items start at the bottom of div like i want it but when it goes up to top it overflows div...and it leaves a gap from where it started from once it overflows top of div....i used overflow:scroll; and overflow:auto; neither works for top of div...then i read somewhere if it had no measures on height that could happened, to i switched from vh/vw to %, then to px...,nothing seems to work....

i seen a youtube video on pong recently and wonder if i have to make collision detection...but before i try that road i wanted to ask your opinions

````
  ```html
  <div id="msgContainer">
    <ol id="msgList"> </ol>
  </div>
  <div id="inputContainer">
    <input id="msg" type="text">
    <input id="listBtn" type="button" value="SEND">
  </div>    


  ```css3
  #msgContainer {
        display:grid;
        position:relative;
        width:360px;
        height:468px;
        align-content:end;
        justify-content:start;
        word-break:break-all;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }

   ```javascript
    var textMsg, createBtn, msgLists, goBackLink, dropDownMenu, x;
    textMsg = document.getElementById("msg");
    createBtn = document.getElementById("listBtn");
    msgsList = document.getElementById("msgList");
    goBackLink = document.getElementById("backHistory");
    x="";
    /* BUTTON AND FUNCTION TO CREATE AND APPEND LIST ITEMS*/
    function createLI() {//function creates list items
        //local variables
        let myLi = document.createElement("li");
        let lineBr = document.createElement("br");
        //sets list items equal to the message values 
        myLi.innerText=textMsg.value;
        //attaches the dynamic list items to predefined ordered list
        msgsList.appendChild(myLi);
        //sets the value of message box to empty after button click
        //thus emptying 
        textMsg.value ="";
        //IF THE MESSAGE IS AN EMPTY STRING IT WILL NOT SHOW LINES
        //BUT IF IT HAS CONTENT IF WILL DISPLAY MESSAGES
       /* if(x=== myLi.innerText) {
            alert("EMPTY STRING");
            myLi.style.display="none";
            return false;
        }else {
            alert("MESSAGE SENT");
            return true;
        } */    
    }
        //add click event listeners to buttons/links 
    createBtn.addEventListener("click", createLI);
    goBackLink.addEventListener("click", goBack);
````

Comment: This is a great explanation of what you **need**  -- However we have nothing to go on without the pertinent code .. Please post your `html` ,  `css` and `JavaScript`  --  Else, be warned, this post will probably be closed.

Comment: Click the `edit` link then the `<>` button on the toolbar to create a code snippet where you can insert your HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Don't worry if it doesn't run, that's where your question comes in.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the code runs...just doing unexpected things...i dont know how to keep it from overflowing the top of the div

Comment: @Zak I appreciate it...yeah i was having trouble figuring out the format for stackoverflow...it wouldnt just let me copy and paste my code...so i had to bluetooth send it from phone text editor to  my tablet and then copy and paste from that editor to here...couldnt properly format it from my phone for some reason...but anyways...i would appreciate your expert opinions

Answer (score 0):

a buddy of mine helped me with the solution:

```
    /*SCROLL FIX*/
    createBtn.addEventListener("click", checkScroll);
    function checkScroll(){

    // outer div
    var msgElement = document.getElementById('msgContainer');

    // getting height of outer div
    var containerHeight = msgElement.clientHeight; // can also use 'offsetHeight' instead of 'clientHeight'

    // inner element (ol)
    var innerElement = document.getElementById('msgList');

    // getting heightof inner element
    var innerHeight = innerElement.clientHeight;

    // compare, to know if scroll is visible or not
    if(containerHeight > innerHeight ){
        msgElement.style.alignContent = "end";
    }
    else if(containerHeight <= innerHeight){
        msgElement.style.alignContent = "unset";
        // making div to auto scroll to bottom, so new chat msg always appears right at the place
        msgElement.scrollTop = msgElement.scrollHeight;

    }
}
```

my first time asking a question here...thought you guys would be more helpful...well i glad i only waited a couple days before i started to talk it over with my friend.